# What's wrong on passing this double pointer and get the value?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new/noob programmer of C++, and I've this problem. I want to pass a pointer of double to a function (which will process some data on it) and read (after the process) a fixed value of that "array". I've do [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afd332e771ea3f6d):

```
void ReadDoubles(double* samples, int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        *samples = i*10.1;
        samples++;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    double *values=0;
    ReadDoubles(values, size);
    cout << *(values+3);
}
```

BUt of course it seems I can't init the pointer that way. I think I need to init the pointer allocating 10 values? Tried:

```
double *values[size];
```

but that's not the solution. How would you do this simple task?

Comment: Try `double values[size];` (and `const int size = 10;`).

Comment: `std::vector<double> values`, pass it by reference...

Comment: @Nim : nope. can't change `ReadDoubles` method.

Comment: @paizza Requirements like that belong in the question.

Comment: @molbdnilo: using `double values[size];` it says "expression did not evaluate to a constant"

Comment: @paizza because `size` is not a constant and C++ does not allow variable length arrays. Change it to `const int size = 10;`

Comment: @paizza You stopped reading halfway through my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate the array at first. Here you are

```
#include <iostream>

void ReadDoubles( double* samples, size_t size )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        *samples = i*10.1;
        samples++;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 10;
    double *values = new double[size];
    //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

    ReadDoubles( values, size );

    std::cout << *(values+3) << std::endl;

    delete []values;
}
```

The program output is

```
30.3
```

If you don't want to use the operator `new` then there are two general approaches. Either you can declare an array as for example

```
int main()
{
    const size_t size = 10;
    //^^^^
    double values[size];
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^  

    ReadDoubles( values, size );

    std::cout << *(values+3) << std::endl;
}
```

or you can use standard class `std::vector<double>`.In this case the function should be rewritten appropriately.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void ReadDoubles( std::vector<double> &samples, size_t size )
{
    samples.resize( size );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    {
        samples[i] = i*10.1;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 10;
    std::vector<double> values;

    ReadDoubles( values, size );

    std::cout << values[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why if I write `double values[size]` it says expression did not evaluate to a constant?

Comment: @paizza: because this is how it is specified in standard.

Comment: I don't want to use "new". new = danger in C++ :D

Comment: @piazza The size in an array declaration shall be a constant expression. You have to write const size_t size = 10; double values[size];

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: i did it. But it says the same. I got the size from another function (which is somethings like `unsigned int GetSize() const { return m_size * m_nch; }`)

Comment: @piazza As I have said the size of an array shall be a constant expression at the compile time. So you need either dynamically to allocate the array or to use std::vector.

Comment: But why with "new" it can allocate that at compile time, and without new I can't? Not sure about this...

Comment: @piazza The compiler needs to know the size of the array to generate object code while using new is equivalent of calling a function at run-time. Opposite to C++ C allows to use variable length arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114536/discussion-between-paizza-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to change the `RealDoubles` function and you must have a function return the size then the following should work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void ReadDoubles(double* samples,int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        *samples = i*10.1; 
        samples++;
    }
}

int get_size()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    int size = get_size(); // get size from function
    //double *values=0;
    double *values = new double[size] {0}; // Use new to allocate array. Optional: use {0} to init first element to 0, others default initialized to 0
    ReadDoubles(values,size);
    cout << *(values+3);
    delete[] values;
}
```

If you prefer to avoid `new` and `delete` then you can let a `std::vector` manage the container for you:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void ReadDoubles(double* samples,int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        *samples = i*10.1; 
        samples++;
    }
}

int get_size()
{
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    int size = get_size(); // get size from function
    //double *values=0;
    std::vector<double> value_container(size,0); // vector will do the new and delete for us
    double *values = value_container.data();
    ReadDoubles(values,size);
    cout << *(values+3);
} // vector destructor will do delete when it goes out of scope
```

Comment: I got the size from a function. It says it cannot evalutate that. Another way?